# Error when using Nativescript's RadSideDrawer

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to add the nativescript-telerik-ui and use the side drawer in a blank project.  The project builds properly, but I am getting the error shown below if I try to run the code on a connected device:

[image]

The project was running correctly until I tried to use the drawer on one of the pages.

Here is my package.json:

```html
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.drawertest",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.4.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.21.0",
    "babel-types": "6.21.0",
    "babylon": "6.14.1",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*"
  }
}
```

I also tried running it in Genymotion.  Here is the error I am getting there:

```html
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.drawertest/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/main-page.xml:20:5
 > Module 'ui/rad-side-drawer' not found for element 'RadSideDrawer'.
   > com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "ui/rad-side-drawer", relative to: app/tns_modules/
      com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1022)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:907)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:895)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:879)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:871)
    com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(android.app.Activity.java)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate(
```

I should probably mention that I getting similar error when I am trying to run the same code on my mac using the ios emulator.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

EDIT:  It turns out I had a syntax error.  Once corrected, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Put xml code too :) and probably you have missing something like xlmns:Drawer or similar things

Comment: @MarekMaszay: good call.  I started looking at the xml and I did have a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log it looks like you have declared an **incorrect namespace** for the RadSideDrawer component ("ui/rad-side-drawer"). That component is part of the *nativescript-telerik-ui* plugin which can be found in the **nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer** module in the node_modules folder.

For more details you can take a look at the official documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/overview).

Simply declare this namespace and use it when declaring the RadSideDrawer in the XML:

```
xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer"
```